# The version of component "Fuzzy Grouping" (40) is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created SSIS Package for Fuzzy Grouping using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

Followings are the components used:
[image]

And executed in the local machine(SQL Server 2008 R2) which works fine. But when I execute it on client machine(SQL Server 2014) it give me the following error:

Error Description:

> Description: The version of component "Fuzzy Grouping" (40) is
>   not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.

**Edit**:

I am using following command to execute package:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "PackagePath" /DECRYPT *** /set \package.variables[ServerName].Value;"\"ServerName\"" 
/set \package.variables[InitialCatalog].Value;"\"DatabaseName""'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think fuzzy grouping is an enterprise level feature.  Is the 2014 instance Standard edition?  Also, if deploying to 2014, I'd use a newer version of SQL Server data tools which is compatible with the target version of SQL Server.